# Reopen vote dialogue box still shows confirmation after cast

Tags: bug, user-interface, vote-to-reopen

I've just noticed that the reopen vote confirmation

> *Nominate this question for reopening?*

was displayed on a post that I've already nominated (and is still collecting votes).  Is this a bug?  I'm not sure if reopen votes can even be rescinded, so I didn't want to click "OK" in case that would happen (assuming *just* the message is incorrect).

Comment: I think you'd get a message like "you have already voted to reopen this question".

Comment: @retailcoder: Right, but I didn't for some reason.  I'll check again whenever I put in another reopen vote.

Comment: Is this still happening?

Comment: @Oded: It's happened a second time, which was sort of recently.  Is it possible for me to test this on a "dummy" question?  In other words: have such a question created and closed, then I'll vote to reopen, and then try again to see if I get the same message.  I can also see what it *does* if I click "OK" again.

Comment: Does this happen after the page refreshes or does it happen without reloading the page?

Comment: @Oded: It happens even after I reload the page.

Comment: OK - thanks for the info. Looking into it.

Comment: @Oded: Alright.  Do you need any additional info (OS, browser, plugins, etc)?

Comment: @Jamal - Don't think those are related, but can't hurt :)

Comment: @Oded: Alright!  **OS:** Windows 7.  **Browser:** Chrome (latest).  **Plugin:** AdBlock Plus.

Comment: @Oded: I've found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176839/after-nominating-to-re-open-link-remains-as-if-you-can-nominate-again), but it's kinda old and has no answers.

Comment: @Oded any updates? It was [also reported on the main Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176839/152859).

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Nothing to report. Looking at the codebase, this isn't trivial. Frankly, the whole way we do these UI bits should be looked at.